# How can I round a number down to 2, even if the number is equal to the nearest 2

Tags: javascript

I would like to round any number down by 2, but also round the number down by 2 if it is exactly divisible by 2.

So for example, 1 is rounded down to 0, 1.5 is rounded down to 0 and 2 is rounded down to 0.

But if the number is greater than 2 and not equal to it, it is rounded to 2 and not 0.

My code so far is `Math.floor(x / 2) * 2`, but this returns 2 instead of 0. How can I code it so it rounds down exact divisions also?

Comment: Should ]2-4] be rounded down to 2, ]4-8] rounded down to 4 and so on?

Comment: 2 - 4 should be rounded to 2 but 4 - 6 should be rounded 4, 6 - 8 should be rounded to 6 thanks

Comment: That's not quite clear. You say 2-4 should round to 2, and 4-6 would round to 4. What about if it's exactly 4? Should that stay as 4?

Answer (score 1):

Your own approach is almost there. It only fails for numbers that are exactly a multiple of 2. You can handle those numbers specifically this way, therefore making the function work for all positive numbers:

```js
function round_down_to_nearest_2(num) {
    const rounded_val = Math.floor(num / 2) * 2;
    return rounded_val === num ? rounded_val - 2 : rounded_val;
}


console.log(round_down_to_nearest_2(1))
console.log(round_down_to_nearest_2(1.5))
console.log(round_down_to_nearest_2(2))
console.log(round_down_to_nearest_2(4))
console.log(round_down_to_nearest_2(4.0001))
console.log(round_down_to_nearest_2(123.0001))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Math.floor((x % 2 == 0 ? (x > 0 ? x - 0.1 : x + 0.1 ): x ) / 2) * 2
```

Comment: Calling this with i.e. `x = 4.01` will incorrectly round it down to `2`. This could of course be fixed by adding more decimals, but it is an inherently flawed method.

Comment: @shmulvad this is exactly what question asked

Comment: No, the question asks for a method that rounds ]0, 2] to `0`, ]2, 4] to `2`, ]4, 6] to `4` etc. Therefore `4` should be rounded down to `2` but `4.00001` should be rounded down to `4`.

Comment: @shmulvad I got it .you'r write

Comment: I fixed the problem